# How do we deal with questions without an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I've observed that old questions with answers that were confirmed to solve the questioner's problem as indicated in the comments or self-answered, yet not marked as accepted.  After a sufficient amount of inactivity these questions bubble up over and over again with "modified x hours ago: Community".

Here's a few examples:

[Place images in page center in epresent-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9703/place-images-in-page-center-in-epresent-mode)

[How can I delete all the gdb related windows/buffers after `q` in gdb CLI window](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7991/how-can-i-delete-all-the-gdb-related-windows-buffers-after-q-in-gdb-cli-window)

[Emacs connect to MySQL (MariaDB) non-interactively](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13555/emacs-connect-to-mysql-mariadb-non-interactively)

Is there anything specific we can do about those to get them marked as accepted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions only bubble up with “modified by Community” if they have no answer that's accepted **or upvoted**. So anyone with at least 15 reputation can stop the question from being bumped by upvoting one of the answers. Of course, upvote only if you're confident that the answer is correct.

Only the asker can mark an answer as accepted. If they haven't accepted an answer, but they've clearly indicated in a comment that they're satisfied with the answer, you may add a comment pointing them to [the help center page “What should I do when someone answers my question?”](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and suggesting that they accept the answer. Do not badger askers into accepting an answer if they haven't indicated that they're satisfied with the answer, it is perfectly valid not to mark any answer as accepted if you find the answers unclear or incomplete.